# Using Facebook API to publish. Getting whitelist error

Tags: json, api, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to publish to facebook from my program, but I'm getting:

```
{"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"(#3) App must be on whitelist"}}
```

I have the following app permissions:

"offline_access", "read_stream", "publish_stream"

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to "like" something, that function is apparently blocked by Facebook, except for apps in their "whitelist".

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to post a status message then try the following syntax:

```
$r=facebook->api("/me/feed", "POST", array("message"=>"YOUR MESSAGE", "access_token"=>$SESSION['access_token']));
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Getting this error when trying to send an inbox message.
Tried all I can think of and googled for, no progress.

I opened a support case here:
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/183144141763793?browse=search_4e8b140cbf26e6040457329